# How to recover Twitter Drafts

Tags: twitter, restore, tweets, data-recovery

I don't what happened but I lost all my Twitter drafts, I draft many tweets for a whole week today somehow there are no drafts, if you know how to restore drafts please let me know I searched online but I can't find anything-

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me and I think it is because I uninstalled the app from my phone. I'm still researching what happened and if I can recover them at all. Unfortunately, the draft tweets are likely gone for good... :/